# navigation rule to close the jsf page

Tags: jsf

I want to close the jsp page window after it returns "finish" from the backing bean.

How do i write the navigation base for this?
I have the following code

```
      <navigation-rule>
      <from-view-id>/faces/script/modify_script.jsp</from-view-id> 
      <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>finish</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id> not sure what to write here</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
  </navigation-rule>
```

Comment: What do you mean with *close* the JSP page window? Why don't just use `window.close()` javascript method instead?

Comment: Also, you sometimes write JSF, sometimes JSP. Which is it?

Comment: @sleske what do you mean?

Comment: I am calling a backing bean method, I want to close the window only when the method return finish.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Read the text: "navigation rule to close the jsf page ... I want to close the jsp page ... faces/script/modify_script.jsp", and the question is tagged "jsf". However, JSP and JSF are different technologies. So OP should correct the question to indicate what s/he means.

Comment: @sleske I read the question and provided a comment showing that this must not be in a navigation rule when it can be handled by JavaScript. JSF works in JSPs, so the question is right tagged. Please if you don't work with JSF, refrain to comment or providing wrong guidance. By the way, there's no navigation rule to close a page.

Comment: Are you using JSF 1.2? Are you using plain JSF or any framework like RichFaces to help you with RIA functionalities like ajax?

Comment: @sleske: JSF can use JSP as view technology. Even though the question is indeed somewhat poorly formulated, it's clearly about JSF. The `<navigation-rule>` is recognizable as essential part of `faces-config.xml` for dealing with navigation in JSF 1.x. The `/faces/` prefix pattern in the `<from-view-id>` entry also confirms once more that it's about a JSF page.

Answer (score 1):

Just return to a view whose sole content is roughly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head><title>Window will be closed</title></head>
    <body><script>window.close()</script></body>
</html>
```

Note that this works only in a browser window which is explicitly been opened by a `window.open()` call in the same webapp. This is not guaranteed to work across all browsers if the browser window in question is been opened by e.g. a `target="_blank"` or manual handling of the enduser (e.g. Ctrl+Click). Most modern browsers will in such case just ignore the close instruction.